# AirDrop on iPad turns off

Tags: ios, ipad, airdrop

The AirDrop feature on my iPad turns itself off (receiving off) after I turn it to receiving on.  I have restarted the iPad and then AirDrop works for a few minutes and then I have the same issue.  I have also reset the network settings.  Same issue.  Air drop is on, and then it goes off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: Also, can I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/347660/edit) your question to include the version of iOS you're running? It may also be worth providing some context on what other devices you're trying to use AirDrop with (i.e. receiving from) on your iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the iOS device: Hold down the On/Off button and the Home button at the same time for at
least ten seconds, until the Apple logo appears.

Make sure WiFi and Bluetooth are turned on. Those are required to use AirDrop and won’t work without them. The try again to turn AirDrop on, if the issue persists you should contact Apppe Support.